# Как в node.js преобразовать код base64 в изображение?

Tags: node.js, base64

Как в node.js преобразовать код base64 в изображение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это в случае если шаблонизатор EJS

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()


app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
var image = iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABaAAAAOECAYAAAB...//BASE64
    res.render('test', {image:image})
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,<%=image%>"/>
</body>
</html>
```